# How to Block UI based on method value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, blockui

I need your help in blocking the form based on the returned value from the method `UpdateDatatable` that will return "Yes", if `commandButton` "Print" is fired. If it is fired, I need to block the UI on the close of the dialog, otherwise not to block it. Currently my code is and it is blocking each time, I am closing the Dialog:

```
<p:dialog id="ss" header="SSS" widgetVar="ss" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
        hideEffect="fade" resizable="false" >
    <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{hrd.UpdateDatatable}"/>
    <p:blockUI trigger="ss" block=":Requests">
        <p:graphicImage width="50" value="/resources/images/ajax.gif">
        </p:graphicImage>
    </p:blockUI>
<<p:commandButton value="Print" id="Print" actionListener="#{hrd.updatePrint}"/>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: What method are you referring to?

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov please refer to the update topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `trigger` and add `widgetVar` to the `p:blockUI` component to be able to trigger it directly.

```
<p:blockUI block=":Requests" widgetVar="blockUIVar">
```

Have your print button set a global js variable.

```
<p:commandButton value="Print" id="Print" actionListener="#{hrd.updatePrint}"
    onclick="window.printClicked = true;"/>
```

Check the variable state and trigger UI block if necessary at the start of the `close` request. Reset variable state in case the dialog could be reopened.

```
<p:ajax event="close" listener="#{hrd.UpdateDatatable}"
    onstart="if (window.printClicked) { PF('blockUIVar').show(); window.printClicked = false; }"/>
```